# Query Activities on Lead

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex, governorlimits

i need to query activities on lead. the idea is i want to get which lead has 10 activities with "unreach" subject and automatically change it to unqualified. i will use **scheduled apex** to daily check if there any lead is matched the criteria but i will get governor limit. here is my code.

```
global class checkPickedLead implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) 
    {   
    List<Lead> leadList2 = new List<Lead>();
    leadList = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE OwnerId='00G90000002zs7H' AND Status = 'Open'];
    List<Task> task = new List<Task>();
    List<Lead> leadToUpdate2 = new List<Lead>{};        
    for(Lead lead:leadList2 ) 
    {        
        task = [Select Id, Subject, WhoId FROM Task WHERE WhoId=:lead.id AND SUBJECT ="unreach"]; //will get governor due SOQL Limit
        if(task.size()>10){
            lead.Status = 'Unqualified';
            update lead; //will get governor limit due DML operation
        }
    }                 
    }
}
```

can you give me sample code to get through this?

Comment: first you are performing DML inside for loop to handle this issue take on more list of Lead and inside for loop after update the status add the lead into new list and ouside of for loop perform DML.. Also instead scheduler use batch I think that will be better option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you can use like this..Query Task based on your list and prepare a map to store your lead Id to all respective task  child records.

In next for you can iterate over map and check how many task records present related to Lead.. and then update lead status accordingly

```
global class checkPickedLead implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) 
    {   
        //map to store lead and respective task record
        map<Id, List<Lead>> mapLeadIdToLstTask = new map<Id, List<Lead>>(); 
        //List too update lead with updated status
        List<Lead> lstleadToUpdate = new List<Lead>(); 

        List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT Id FROM Lead 
                                WHERE OwnerId='00G90000002zs7H' 
                                  AND Status = 'Open'];

        for(Task objTask:[Select Id, Subject, WhoId 
                            FROM Task WHERE WhoId IN: leadList 
                             AND SUBJECT ="unreach"]) 
        {   
            //Use a map to store all the child tasks related to Lead
            if(!mapLeadIdToLstTask.containsKey(objTask.WhoId))
                mapLeadIdToLstTask.put(objTask.WhoId, new List<Task>{objTask});
            else
                mapLeadIdToLstTask.get(objTask.WhoId).add(objTask);
        }   
        for(Id leadId: mapLeadIdToLstTask.keySet())
        {
            //check if Task size is more than 10 then update that lead status
             if(mapLeadIdToLstTask.get(leadId).size()>10){ 
                lstleadToUpdate.add(new Lead(Id = leadId, lead.Status = 'Unqualified'));
            }
        }
        update lstleadToUpdate;          
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Ratan, thanks for your response, i already try your code and fix some mistype but i get error 'method does not exist `Map<Id,List<Task>>.containsKey()`'

Comment: @FebrianTarigan ohh check updated ans..this should be `mapLeadIdToLstTask.containsKey(objTask.WhoId)`

Comment: @FebrianTarigan is this issue resolved ?

Comment: Sorry @Ratan for late reply. somehow this code didn't work as expected. it didn't get id that have 10 activities

Comment: @FebrianTarigan have you checked the debug logs.. may be you are using wrong ownerId to fwtch lead records...

Comment: the ownerId is the queue id. i already check the debug logs but it only get 1 lead record (i have 100 lead records)

Comment: @FebrianTarigan 100 lead records with ownerId = same querId what you mentioned in your question.. I suggest first perform simple query in developer console and check query returning how many records or not..

Comment: Hi @Ratan, already found the problem. it didnt get the record because it get error on validation rules. Thanks man!

Comment: how can i cover keyset and containskey method. i only get 68% of my test class :( can you give me direction please?

Comment: @FebrianTarigan yeah I can help can you please add a new question with your query and issue where you have stuck ?